# Get the text from a YouTube page with bs4

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, youtube

I would love some help, thanks!

I am trying to get only the text from a YouTube page with no success, it's giving me something, but it's not the text.

I tried the code on several URLs of YouTube and it's giving me pretty much the same outputs, also, i tried the code on different URLs(not YouTube) and it gave me the text of the website.

The code:

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def read_url(url):
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987 Safari/537.36'}
    request = urllib.request.Request(url,headers=headers)
    html = urllib.request.urlopen(request,timeout=5).read()
    return html
def parse(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,features='lxml')
    for script in soup(["script", "style",'[document]','head', 'title','\n']):
        script.extract()
    data = soup.get_text()
    return data

def get_text(url):
    html = read_url(url)
    text = parse(html)
    return text

def main():
    url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lAe1cqCOXo'
    print(get_text(url))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The output:

```
About
Press
Copyright
Contact us
Creators
Advertise
Developers
Terms
Privacy
Policy & Safety
Test new features
```

Comment: You need to include the element for which you want the text in the list which already has "script", "style", '[document]'...  etc.

Comment: can you give an example of element? @MahendraSinghMeena